# Find a suitable neighborhood of the diagonal

Tags: general-topology

While reading the book [Introduction to Dynamical Systems](https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/%7Efejoz/Enseignement/ds2021/Brin-Stuck_2002_Introduction-to-Dynamical-Systems.pdf) (by Michael Brin and Garrett Stuck), I got stuck with Proposition 2.1.3. The authors make a claim without proof:

> Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, $x\in X$ and $U$ be a
> neighborhood of $x$. Prove: there is an open neighborhood $W$ of $x$
> in $X$ with $W\subseteq U$ and an open neighborhood $V$ of the
> diagonal set $\Delta\subseteq X\times X$ (endowed with the product
> topology) such that: if $y\in W$ and $(y,z)\in V$, then $z\in U$.

I tried to prove it myself and referred to textbooks at hand. I think the claim is related to the notion: "uniform space", which gives neighborhoods of the diagonal set $\Delta$. However, I'm new in general topology and I'm not familiar with this aspect. Could anyone give me a hint? Would appreciate.

**EDIT:** The diagonal set is defined as: $\Delta=\{(x,x)|x\in X\}\subseteq X\times X$, an open neighborhood $V$ of $\Delta$ means: $\Delta\subseteq V$ and $V\subseteq X\times X$ is open in the product space $X\times X$.

Comment: Can you define the diagonal set $\Delta$? I would think $\Delta = \{(x,x) \mid x \in X\}$, but from this it is obvious that if $V \subseteq \Delta$ and $(y,z) \in V$, then $z = y$.

Comment: @TheSurgeonofDeath The definition is added.

Answer (score 1):

Construct open $W\subseteq U$ such that the closure of $W$ is contained in $U$. This is possible because $X$ is compact Hausdorff, hence normal. Let $C$ denote the complement of the closure of $W$. Then
$$
V=(U\times U)\cup(C\times C)
$$
is a neighborhood of $\Delta$. If $y\in W$ and $(y,z)\in V$, then $(y,z)\notin C\times C$, so $(y,z)\in U\times U$, which in turn leads to $z\in U$.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can prove this claim myself. Here is my answer:

**Fact 1.**   *A compact Hausdorff space is normal ($T_4$)*, see [Introduction to Topology, Proposition 5.1.9](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-981-13-6954-4).

**Fact 2.** *The diagonal set $\Delta$ is closed in a Hausdorff space*, see [Introduction to Topology, Proposition 4.4.2](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-981-13-6954-4).

**Fact 3.** *If $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, so is $X\times X$*, see  [Introduction to Topology, Theorem 4.4.4 and Theorem 5.1.14](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-981-13-6954-4).

Observe that we only need to find disjoint neighborhoods to separate closed sets $\overline{W}\times (X\setminus U)$ and $\Delta$. We choose any open neighborhood $W$ of $x$ with $\overline{W}\subseteq U$ (use Fact 1 to separate $\{x\}$ and $X\setminus U$). Thus $\overline{W}\times (X\setminus U)$ and $\Delta$ are two disjoint closed sets in $X\times X$ (by Fact 2); by   Fact 3, $X\times X$ is also a compact Hausdorff space, thus we can find disjoint neighborhoods to separate them (by Fact 1 again). The proof is complete.